# What is wrong with this jquery validation code?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net

The code is supposed to hide the textbox when the page loads and make it visible only when the user selects Other.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ddlMajor').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Other') {
                //                $('#txtOther').show();
         $('#txtOther').css('display', 'inline');
         }
        else {
                //                $('#txtOther').hide();
        $('#txtOther').css('display', 'block');
        }

        });

});
</script>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOther" style="display:none;" > </asp:TextBox>

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlMajor">
                 <asp:ListItem Value="Accounting">Accounting</asp:ListItem> 
                 <asp:ListItem Value="Management">Management</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML generated by the asp.net code?

Comment: I don't think that the ID that you set in ASP:dropdownList is the same as the ID that's generated in the resulting HTML.  What do you get when you look at this in a tool like Firebug or IE debugger?

Comment: Display Inline and Display Block are both going to be visible. If you want to hide it you would use display none.

Comment: Remember that if your ASP.NET code is running within a master page or user control, etc., the ID you give a control may not be the actual ID output to the page -- .NET will often add a prefix.  You can use the `clientId` property to insert the correct IDs.

Comment: Hi Dismissile - This is the answer. I need to make the display:none Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As you are using a Server Side control the ID will be re-rendered. You could put code blocks in your javascript, but I would recommend using a class instead:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOther" style="display:none;" CssClass="txtOther"> </asp:TextBox>

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlMajor" CssClass="ddlMajor">
                 <asp:ListItem Value="Accounting">Accounting</asp:ListItem> 
                 <asp:ListItem Value="Management">Management</asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

 $('.ddlMajor').change(function () {
...
});
```

I also believe your CSS `display` values are incorrect. Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ddlMajor').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Other') {
         $('.txtOther').css('display', 'block');
         }
        else {
        $('.txtOther').css('display', 'none');
        }

        });
```

---

Or if you do not want to change Markup, use `ClientID`. Note: This will only work when youve got the javascript contained within the .aspx file

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= ddlMajor.ClientID %>').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Other') {
         $('#<%= txtOther.ClientID %>').css('display', 'block');
         }
        else {
        $('#<%= txtOther.ClientID %>').css('display', 'none');
        }

        });
```

Comment: Should use <%= ddlMajor.ClientID %> etc. rather then using CssClass to point at objects that you might need for what it should be used for.

Comment: Why is this? Do you have a reference? What if the javascript is contained in a .js file? How would you do this?

Comment: If separating the JS from the aspx file you can still have JS variables to set the IDs of Server Controls. What I'm just saying is that using CssClass to solve this problem might cause problems later on when need to use CssClass for its purpose. Coder and Web Designer is not always the same person :)

Comment: Fair point @StefanE, I forget that sometimes the markup has been committed and cannot be changed freely. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that when you try to hide the textbox, you set its display to `block`.  JQuery uses the display property `display: none` to hide the textbox.  So what you're doing is overwriting jQuery's hiding.  Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddlMajor').change(function () {
        $('#txtOther').css('display', 'inline');
        if ($(this).val() == 'Other') {
            $('#txtOther').show();
        } else {
            $('#txtOther').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This isn't the only issue. jQuery won't find any `#ddlMajor` elements as this will be re-rendered client side. See my answer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize ASP would rewrite the id tag.  Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use classes as references but as the server controls will have a different ID when rendered you can use inline( <%= ddlMajor.ClientID %> ) instead to get the proper ID:

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#<%= ddlMajor.ClientID %>").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Other') {
                $('#<%= txtOther.ClientID %>').show();

         }
        else {
                $('#<%= txtOther.ClientID %>').hide();

        }

        });

    });
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account the issue with the CSS display, or the fact `#txtOther` will be rerendered too.

Comment: Well, using class as in your answer is the wrong recommendation when working with jQuery and ASP.NET.. I pointed out the problem of that the javascript code he have will never be executed unless having the correct id.

Comment: I still wouldn't say its a correct answer to the initial question.